# Integrating BuildBot into JIRA

Tags: integration, jira, jira-plugin, buildbot

We have a [BuildBot](http://buildbot.net/) setup for our continuous build. Additionally, we happen to use JIRA for all our bug-tracking and task needs.

What I was trying to accomplish (and have found little to no information on) is integrating build numbers (from builds generated) into JIRA. Specifically, I need two fields:

- **Found In Build** (dropdown listing previous builds to a certain threshold allowing QA to simply select the build number)
- **Resolved In Build** (another dropdown allowing Engineers to select a *future* build that will contain the fix)

Ultimately I would like these fields to be required fields as well, but that is the simpler task to accomplish.

After researching this for several days, I have not been able to find any reference, plugin or even a hint on how to accomplish this; your help is needed.

Please post complete answers rather than code-snippets, that way your efforts will not go unused/misunderstood.

P.S. JIRA Version: **5.2** BuildBot: **0.8.4p2**

Comment: Probably you should ask in buildbot mailing list which is the official support channel they have

Answer (score 0):

This is not a direct solution, but [bamboo](http://www.atlassian.com/software/bamboo) is tight integrated to jira and display automatically this informations and others in jira and vice versa.